# Linking sub menus to variations

Tags: 2010, navigation, variations

I have a publishing site with variations, the directory structure is laid out like this:

```
en-us
-products
--product1
--product2
-contact us
-news
euro
-products
--product1
--product3
-contact us
-news
```

..etc.  However the customer wants the navigation menus laid out like this:

```
products
-en-us
--product1
--product2
-euro
--product1
--product3
contact us
news
```

While still having variations on the 'contact us' and 'news' pages.  Selecting a product from en-us should switch the whole site to the `en-us` variation, and selecting a product from the euro variation should do switch to the `euro` variation.

I was thinking of writing a custom nav provider, is that the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, what do you mean under variation? Locale, Design, etc?